# Issue with custom fonts with jsPDF in my Angular project

Tags: angular, fonts, jspdf

I am using the 1.4.1 version of jsPDF in my Angular 5 project.

I'm trying to add some custom fonts to my pdf but it's not working.
It throws the following error :

```
Font does not exist in FileInVFS, import fonts or remove declaration doc.addFont('nameOfTheFont').
```

So i tried to add files to VFS like this :

```
doc.addFileToVFS(nameOfTheFont, FontBase64Encoded);
```

And it's not throwing errors anymore, the PDF is well generated but the font is not working at all in the pdf.

After a lot of RD, I tried to add "WinAnsiEncoding" at the end and it get better (just a little because instead of unreadable characters, i have now default font characters).

```
doc.addFont(nameOfTheFont, nameOfTheFont,"normal","WinAnsiEncoding");
```

Even if it is still throwing the same error message, I do now see the name of the font when i do a `console.log(doc.getFontList());` but it's not displaying the proper font when i set it.

Any help will be welcome. Thanks !